# Find complex roots of $x^2+x+1$

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm quite inept when it comes to calculations with complex numbers, and my task is to find complex roots of $x^2+x+1$. Well obviously they are $x_1=-\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $x_2=-\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}$. But how come when I put the quadratic function into WolphramAlpha it gives back $-\sqrt[3]{-1}$ (cubic root) and $(-1)^{2/3}$. How could I deduce it on my own?

Comment: $x^2+x+1 = (x^3-1)/(x-1)$

Comment: These $x_1$ and $x_2$ *are* the cubic roots of $1$ (together with $1$ itself). You can just calculate their cubes and see for yourself.

Comment: Let $x^2+x+1=0$ and either (1) use the quadratic formula, or (2) complete the square.

Comment: @Arek Krawczyk : WolframAlpha's form of the answer is bizarre, opaque, and simply not the best way to write the answer.  I feel your pain.  I suggest you give WolframAlpha people some "feedback" (they have a link you can click on to do this).  Even worse, using standard conventions for raising real numbers to fractional powers,   $(-1)^\frac{2}{3}$ is $1$, which does not solve the equation.  Also, the cube root of a real number is a real number (unless you explain otherwise), so the first answer it gave is $-(-1)$ which equals $1$.  So you can argue persuasively that the answers...

Comment: ...are not merely confusing but wrong.  This is an easy problem and WolframAlpha should be able to give you correct answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom line is that you are right and WolframAlpha is wrong.  You can try to explain away wny WolframAlpha gave the answers that it did, but WolframAlpha's answers violate standard rules for radicals and fractional exponents applied to real numbers, and there are good reasons for those rules existing.  Without such rules, you can prove such absurdities as $1 = \sqrt{1}=\sqrt{(-1)(-1)}=\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}=i*i=-1$.

If $x$ is a real number, then, unless one carefully explains otherwise (which WolframAlpha did not), $\sqrt[3]{x}$ is defined as the unique real cube root of $x$, so WolframAlpha's first answer $-\sqrt[3]{-1}$ is equal to $-(-1)$, which equals $1$, which does not solve the equation.  If $x$ is a real number, then, unless one carefully explains otherwise (which WolframAlpha did not) ${x}^\frac{2}{3}$ is defined as the square of the unique real cube root of $x$, so WolframAlpha's second answer,$({-1})^\frac{2}{3}$, also equals $1$.

Why did WolframAlpha give the answers it did? Well, one of the *complex* cube roots of $-1$ is $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{{\sqrt 3}}{2}i$,  and if you multiply 
$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{{\sqrt 3}}{2}i$ by $-1$, you get one of the solutions of your equation.  That might explain WolframAlpha's first answer.  If you square  $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{{\sqrt 3}}{2}i$, you get the other answer to your equation, and that would seem to explain Wolfram Alpha's second answer.

Wolfram Alpha seems to be calculating "the cube root" of $-1$ by taking its logarithm using the "principal branch" of the logarithm, which gives you $\pi i$, dividing the result by $3$, and then taking the exponential of the result.  But the bottom line is that WolfAlpha is giving you answers to a simple quadratic equation that are at best confusing and that one can convincingly argue are incorrect.

An alternative, correct way to write the solutions is $\exp(2\pi i/3)$ and $\exp(4\pi i/3)$.  This is similar to what WolframAlpha seems to be trying to do but it has an unambiguous meaning.

Comment: Thank you so much for such an in-depth analysis of my problem :) I'll write to Wolfram folks right away.

Comment: @ArekKrawczyk : related problem: I wrote to them to complain that WolframAlpha would not graph $x^\frac{2}{3}$ correctly from $x=-1$ to $1$ (Maple doesn't do it either unless you use some command such as "surd", which you shouldn't have to ).

Answer (score 2):

$0=x^{2}+x+1=\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}+\frac{3}{4}=\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}-\left(\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^{2}=\left(x+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\left(x+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$

*Kwadraat afsplitsen* in Dutch. I don't know the English equivalent for it.

Comment: Completing the square.

Comment: @Arthur tibi gratias ago.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to see is that $(x-1)(x^2+x+1)=x^3-1$. Of course, $1$ is a root of that last equation, as are the roots of your polynomial. But this means that (writing your root as $\omega$), we have $\omega^3=1$! Similarly, if $x^n+...+1=0$, then $x^{n+1}=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2+x+1=0$ when $x=\frac{-1\frac{+}{-}\sqrt{1-4}}{2} \Rightarrow \frac{-1\frac{+}{-}\sqrt{3}i}{2}\Rightarrow x=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}},e^{\frac{4\pi i}{3}}$. It then follows that,

$(e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}})^2+e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}+1=e^{\frac{4\pi i}{3}}+e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}+1=e^{\frac{-2\pi i}{3}}+e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}+1=-1+1=0$

Argue similarly for the latter $x$.

Comment: How did you  made the transition to $e^{\dfrac{2\pi}{3}}$?

Comment: Using Euler's formula, $e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$

Answer (score 1):

$(1)$. Use the [quadratic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula):

$$ax^2+bx+c=0\iff x_{1,2}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

$(2)$. Use the **Re[...]** and **Im[...]** functions of *Mathematica* and/or *Wolfram Alpha* to determine the real and imaginary parts of these complex numbers.

$(3)$. My personal favorite: **ALL** n<sup>th</sup>-order roots of unity form a regular polygon with *n* sides, whose center is in $0$, and always has one corner in $1$, while the coordinates of the others coincide with the rest of its $n-1$ points. The argument (or angle) which each of these forms with the horizontal axis is a multiple of the n<sup>th</sup> part of $2\pi=360^0$, and their absolute value (the length of the straight line segment uniting each of them with $0$) is $1$. See the two pictures [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity) for the cases $n=3$ and $n=5$.